# How to implement sorted pointer vector?

Tags: c++, containers

I want to implement a sorted pointer vector, like the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

//! A random accessed vector with sorted allocated elements.
//! - Elements must be allocated on heap.
//! - The vector manages the memories of its elements.
template<class T, class Compare = std::less<T>>
class SortedPtrVector
{
public:
    SortedPtrVector()   {}

    //! Add an element, return its index.
    int Add(T* element)
    {
        auto position = std::lower_bound(m_vector.begin(), m_vector.end(), 
            element, Compare); // Wrong here due to compare smart pointers
        auto newPosition = m_vector.insert(position, element);
        return newPosition - m_vector.begin();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> m_vector;
};
```

How to implement the Add function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apart from question of implementing comparison for smart pointers, why not use a map/multimap instead of vector if elements have to be sorted? For comparison, won't a wrapper for std::less<T> comparing objects pointers point to using std::less work?

Comment: I want the elements to be random accessed. They are put under a tree node as tree items, like a file folder structure. When add a new file, I first find its position (row index) under the tree node and then add it to the position. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto position = std::lower_bound(m_vector.begin(), m_vector.end(), 
        element, Compare);
```

This is obviously wrong. `Compare` is a type, not an object.

You could use lambda with an object of `Compare`. So I think this should work:

```
Compare cmp; 
auto comparer = [&](std::unique_ptr<T> const & a, std::unique_ptr<T> const & b)
                {
                   return cmp(*a, *b); //use cmp here!
                };

std::unique_ptr<T> uniqElem(element); 

auto position = std::lower_bound( m_vector.begin(), 
                                  m_vector.end(), 
                                  uniqElem, //not element!!
                                  comparer);
```

Note that you cannot pass `element` to `std::lower_bound`, as `element` is of type `T*`, when the `std::lower_bound` expects the value of type `std::unique_ptr<T>` and there is no implicit conversion from `T*` to `std::unique_ptr<T>`. Also, you cannot insert `element` to the vector for the same reason. Insert `uniqElem` to the vector.

I would suggest you to take the argument as `unique_ptr` instead of `T*`, because that indicates to the user that the added item will be deleted automatically when an object of `SortedPtrVector` goes out of scope:

```
int Add(T* element);                 //bad - doesn't say element will be deleted!
int Add(std::unique_ptr<T> element); //good - says element will be deleted!
```

If you use `std::unique_ptr<T>` as parameter type, then note these points:

```
v.Add(new T());                     //will not work
v.Add(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());  //will work

std::unique_ptr<T> item(new T()); 
v.Add(item);                        //will not work
v.Add(std::move(item));             //will work
```

It is all because `std::unique_ptr` is NOT *copyable*, but it is *moveable*.

Comment: Any special to use Add(std::unique_ptr<T> element) function? It seems there is no public copy constructor for unique_ptr.

Comment: @user1899020: Yes, you have call it like this : `v.Add(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());`. It will not work if you write this: `std::unique_ptr<T> item(new T()); v.Add(item);`. But it will work if you write this : `v.Add(std::move(item));`. It is all because `std::unique_ptr` is NOT *copyable*, but it is *moveable*.

Comment: Is it too cumbersome? May I just call v.Add(new T())?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `std::less` you can implement your own `ptr_less` like this:

```
template< typename T >
class ptr_less
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    bool operator ()( T const& left, T const& right ) const
    {
        return *left < *right;
    }
};
```

A general implementation would have to check for *null pointers* as well.

Another approach would be to use `boost::ptr_vector` instead of `std::vector`.